# Creating object(n)

Tags: c#, object

How would one create a series of objects which are named `object(x)` where `x` is a number? like something like

```
int x = 1;
Object object(x) = new Object();
```

Every answer will be appreciated!

Comment: List<List<object> objects = new List<List<object>();

Comment: Array, list, dictionary; plenty of ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using `Dictionary<int, Object>` which is close to the desired syntax:

```
  int x = 1;

  // If you insist on object as a name you have to use @ prefix
  // since object is a reserved word
  Dictionary<int, Object> @object = new Dictionary<int, object>();

  @object.Add(1, new object());

  ...

  // If you want to access the istance use @object[x]

  object myObject = @object[x];
```